# Find the infimum of a set

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $x$ be a positive irrational number and let $A = \{m+nx: m,n \in\mathbb{Z} , m+nx>0\}$. Prove that $\inf A=0$.

So far, I have the following:
Let $a = m+nx$. $A$ is a set of positive real numbers. So $0<a, \forall a \in A$, thus $0$ is a lower bound for $A$. Since $0$ is a lower bound of $A$, then we say $A$ is bounded by definition. We know that $\inf A$ exists by the completeness axiom.

Comment: This is a good start  :)  In fact, the statement written here is false (if $x=1$, then every element of $A$ is a positive integer, hence $\ge1$). Is there a missing hypothesis that $x$ is irrational?

Comment: $x$ should not be a rational number, I guess. otherwise, the $\inf$ would be equal to $x$

Comment: @Amirhossein You went a bit too far in your comment. 
 If $x=p/q$ in reduced form, the infimum would be $1/q$, not $x$

Comment: Yes, you are right. my fault. @BrianMoehring

Comment: Right.  So $\inf A$ exists.  And $\inf A \ge 0$.  The prove that $\inf A = 0$ we must show that  for every $r > 0$ then $r$ is not a lower bound. In other words for any real $r > 0$ we can find and $a=m+nx \in A$ so that $a=m+nx < r$.  That's our goal.

Comment: Is this true?  If $x = 1$ then $\{m+nx> 0\} = \{m+n>0\}$ and $\inf A = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

To show that the infimum of the above set is zero when ever $x$ is a positive irrational number, Suppose that the $\inf A$ is equal to $a > 0$, the every element of $A$ should be a integer multiple of $a$, otherwise let $a_1 < a_2$ and $  a < a_1 , a_2 \leq 2a$ then $a_2 - a_1 \leq a$ and it is also a member of the set $A$. But this contradicts the fact the $a$ is the infimum of $A$. Thus, $a_2 - a_1 =0$ So $a$ should belong to $A$. Now let $b$ an other element of $A$, then $b - k \times a \leq a$, where $k$ is the floor of $\frac{b}{a}$. So every element of $A$ is a integer multiple of $a$ and that means that $x$ is a rational number. Contradiction.

Comment: In your explanation is a = m+nx, like it states in my reasoning? Or is it just an arbitrary number? @Amirhossein